# Find the turning points of $(x^{2} + y^{2})^{2} = x^ {2} - y^{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Using implicit differentiation I found the derivative of this function. Here is my working:

[image: Working]

but how would I evaluate the numerator as $0$ when $2x - 4x^3 - 4xy^2 = 0$?

I tried moving all the $x$ terms to one side and all the $y$ terms to the other but to no avail. The answer is supposed to be $x = \pm \frac{\sqrt6}{4}$ and $y = \pm \frac{\sqrt2}{4}$. How do I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out a factor of $2x$:

$$2x(1 - 2x^2 - 2y^2) = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow 2x = 0, \ 1 - 2x^2 - 2y^2 = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow x = 0, x^2+y^2 = \frac{1}{2}.$$

The turning points must also lie on the original curve $(x^2+y^2)^2 = x^2 - y^2$. Can you continue?

Comment: Thanks, I substituted $x^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{2}$ into the equation of the original curve and got the answer, but how do I prove that $x = 0$ is not a solution (if $x = 0$, $y = 0$, so the derivative is $\frac{0}{0}$)

Comment: As you said, when $x = 0$, substituting into the original curve gives $y = 0$. Then the derivative is $\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined, so $x = 0$ is not a solution. If you graph the curve, you will see it that the curve passes through the origin twice, giving two different slopes at the same time.

Comment: Isn't that indeterminate form?

Comment: Yes, I meant 'indeterminate' instead of undefined.